# discord.py change permission of text channel on on_member_join

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot that gives member on on_member_join read_messages = False. I am only able to achieve this when I iterate through all possible discord text channels in a for loop, but I would only want to do it for a specific channel. I know how to create a channel and give it read_messages = False, but I need to do it on a already existing channel.

My current code:

```
import time
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import random
from discord.utils import get
import asyncio

load_dotenv()
DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if member.guild.id == 599754972228888888:
        print("Correct guild. New  member: " + str(member))
    else:
        return
    guild = client.get_guild(599754972228888888)
    channel = client.get_channel(517974569018888888)
    print(guild.channels)
    for cha in channel.channels:
        await cha.set_permissions(member, read_messages=False)


client.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Is there any reason to not simply deny the @everyone-role reading permission for that specific channel from your Discord server settings?
2. Assuming `channel = client.get_channel(517974569018888888)` is the channel you want to adjust the permissions for, you can deny the reading permissions directly doing

```py
await channel.set_permissions(member, read_messages=False)
```

3. If `channel` is not the channel you want or there's some dynamic involved, you can use [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get) to get the channel by providing e.g. the channel name and then proceed with 2.

---

Neither of the solutions needs the for loop, it can be eliminated entirely

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make a text channel which is able to see only for administrators or verified user or smth like that.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):

    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name="NAME")
    await channel.set_permissions(member, read_messages=False)
```

If you want to set perms for everyone do this:

```
@client.command()
@command.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def setperms(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild

    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="@everyone")
    
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name="NAME")
    await channel.set_permissions(member, read_messages=False)
```

Replace NAME with name of your channel